# how to iterate through replace() function python

Tags: python, text, str-replace

I am trying to iterate through my replace() function, to remove [1:n] in my .txt file (see image below), but it does not seem to work.

[image]

I have tried multiple things:

```
with open('glad.txt', 'rt') as f:
  content = f.read()
  for line in content:
    for x in range(118):
      z = line.replace(f"[{x}]", "")
  f.close()    
print(z)
```

also:

```
with open('glad.txt', 'rt') as f:
  content = f.read()
  test = open("out.txt", "wt")
  for line in content:
    for x in range(120):
      z = test.write(line.replace(f"[{x}]", ""))
  f.close()
print(z)
```

But both without success.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, of course, so for instance the data contains the following sentence: "[113][114][115] Een paar dagen voor de inhuldiging protesteerde de lokale Turkse gemeenschap tegen de oprichting van het monument.[116]" and I expect the output to be: "Een paar dagen voor de inhuldiging protesteerde de lokale Turkse gemeenschap tegen de oprichting van het monument." @ohthatgeoff if that answers your question.

Comment: line.replace does not modify line, it modifies z.  Also, f.close is not needed with the `with` context manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses the [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function to replace those characters.

```
import re

text = """
OK this is some text. [123][456][789]
just some more text.[007]
"""

output = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', text)

print(output)
```

Output

```
OK this is some text.
just some more text.
```

Update:

Adding a file reading example. Make sure to pass the file as the first argument to the script.

```
import re
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:
    text = fin.read()

output = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', text)

print(output)
```

Comment: I tried doing it like this:

import re

with open('glad.txt', 'rt') as f:
  content = f.read()
  output = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', content)
print(output)

but this game me a blank output

Comment: Updated the answer to have a file reading example, hopefully that helps.